# php/html: click counter doesn't work

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a click count, each time the button is clicked will call an incrementClickCount() function that will set the variable $count=0 as static, increment the $count variable and display it. I don't understand why it's not working.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Click Counter</title>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['clicks'])){
            incrementClickCount();
        }

        function incrementClickCount(){
            static $count=0;
            $count++;
            echo $count . " and counting...";
        }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <input type="submit" name="clicks" value="click me!">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: static is not kept across requests, you need to save your counter somewhere

Comment: ok, I will try session instead. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when the function incrementClickCount() is called, you $counter is always set to 0 and incremented...you need to declare you $counter variable only once a save it somewhere, to session for example

Comment: I don't know session yet, but I will check it out and test it. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, I hope it helped. If you will have problems with it, i am ready to help you ;)

Comment: Thanks! I try session and it worked properly. I'll put the code below for others who want help.

Comment: Nice work! Just a detail, in function incrementClickCount() when the session isnt set; there was already click and session should be 1 instead of 0 I think :)

Answer (score 0):

For those who is struggling with the same problem. Here is my code fixed. Thanks a lot for those who helped me. Was suggested by Zdenek Leitkep and Andrey to use sessions instead.
I discover how to use it here: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sessions: Click Counter</title>
    <?php
        session_start();
        if(isset($_POST['clicks'])){
            incrementClickCount();
        }

        function incrementClickCount(){
            if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
                $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
            }else{
                $_SESSION['count']++;
                print $_SESSION['count'];
            }
        }
    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <input type="submit" name="clicks" value="click me!">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```